# Could not read from remote repository

Tags: github, aptana

I have received the following error multiple times:

> Could not read remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

I am very confused about how to remedy this error.

Comment: Have you tried cloning the repository using the command line version of Git? Are you trying to pull using HTTPS or SSH?

Comment: I don't understand the down vote. In any case, I also encounter this error message when attempting to checkout private repositories. Public repositories don't seem to have this problem.

Comment: I am trying pull using SSH and i am getting same error

Answer (score 21):

Make sure you are using the correct SSH keys/usernames on both your GitHub account and your local machine. Here's how you can
[do that on GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys#platform-windows)

Also, you might consider using an alternative Git manager. I've never heard of Aptana, but I do know that GitHub has an awesome [GUI](http://windows.github.com/) program for managing your repositories.

In the future, this is all much easier and more streamlined on Linux/Unix operating systems like Ubuntu. Ubuntu is geared towards developers and has things like Git and SSH installed correctly by default.

Answer (score 9):

I had the exact same issue with a private repo.
Cloning through the same error both through https and ssh

Then I made a commit through github (simply updated the `README.md` with an empty line)

Surprisingly enough, this resolved the issue. It would be nice to know why though!

Comment: I had the same issue this morning and your answer resolved it for me as well. One clue that it was not a problem with my SSH key (or authentication in general): I had a number of repositories from the same account but only one was affected.

Answer (score 7):

[image: Click this]

I had the same problem - it was caused by me using the SSH key instead of the HTTPS URL. I created my repository by importing a project via Intellij and it must have pushed via HTTPS.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you have done the proper SSH keys configuration according to github's [instructions](https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/) it might be a problem of pull with https and later pushing with git+ssh

to make it more clear

if you have used https to pull

```
git pull https://github.com/user/repo.git
```

then you have changed remote URL

```
git remote set-url origin git+ssh://github.com/user/repo.git
```

and tried to push after some changes and commits

```
git push origin master
```

you might get this error it happened to me

erase the local repository and re-clone using git+ssh

```
git pull git+ssh://github.com/user/repo.git
```

and now your push should work

Answer (score 4):

**ssh-add -A** resolved my issue in *MacOS Sierra 10.12.6*.

I had no problem both for public and private repo before.

Today I tried to clone or git pull for private repo, but it hit the above issues.

After search around, this is the perfect solution for me.

Comment: Chrs for the Bryan - would you be able to elaborate a little more on what the `ssh-add -A` does?

Answer (score 4):

On Windows open file:
`C:\Users\<USER_NAME>\.ssh\config`

You should have your host defined in the "config" file:

```
host gitlab.com
 HostName gitlab.com
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_user_private_key

host bitbucket.org
 HostName bitbucket.org
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_user_private_key

host github.com
 HostName github.com
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_user_private_key
```

Comment: I had "host github" on the first line of the github section, rather than "host github.com". Thanks!

Comment: Resolved my issue, thanks! If `config` is missing, copy `id_rsa_X`, rename to `config`, edit in Notepad and paste in the contents above. Use `#` to comment out sections that are not required.

Answer (score 4):

### Try these 3 Simple Steps:

It's pretty straight forward. See the 3 step summary of the links below.

1. Check for [the existence of SSH keys](https://help.github.com/en/articles/checking-for-existing-ssh-keys). If one exists, then great: you can use it. If not, then you will have [to create one](https://help.github.com/en/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent).
2. You will need to [add the ssh key to the ssh-agent](https://help.github.com/en/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent#adding-your-ssh-key-to-the-ssh-agent). If the agent is snoozing on the job, then you will need to wake the agent by writing this to your console/terminal: `eval $(ssh-agent -s)`. Then you can simply add the key,
3. Try pushing your repository. Hopefully it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue on my private Ubuntu server using ssh.

My workaround solution was:

**open shell on my private server**

```
git init --bare /path/<myapp>.git
```

and then, **from my developer laptop**

```
git push <remote_repo> <local branch>
```

has finally worked well.

PS:

I've never tried, but remote repo with https seems working better than ssh.

I hope this help.

Comment: The --bare was what I was missing. Thx so  much.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to setting the identity files in the ssh config, I also had to set the git remote to the right user - complete solution in https://www.keybits.net/post/automatically-use-correct-ssh-key-for-remote-git-repo/

```
vi ~/.ssh/config
Host github.com-myuser
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/mykey
```

I made sure I had this identity file loaded with ssh-add -l

```
ssh-add -l
4096 SHA256:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX mykey (RSA)
```

Then I set my remote to include the right user

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com-myuser:myuser/myrepo.git
```

Then the push worked

```
git push -u origin master
Enumerating objects: 146, done.
Counting objects: 100% (146/146), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (144/144), done.
Writing objects: 100% (146/146), 9.71 MiB | 7.48 MiB/s, done.
Total 146 (delta 10), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (10/10), done.
To git@github.com-myuser:myuser/myrepo.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

Voila

Comment: thank you ! you saved me.. the one thing I did is add -user after git@github.com in ssh and set remote url again.

Answer (score 0):

If you have updated you OSX recently you have to call `ssh-add -A`. Have a look at this answer: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254468/macos-sierra-doesn-t-seem-to-remember-ssh-keys-between-reboots

Answer (score 0):

Installing a root/CA Certificate

Given a CA certificate file foo.crt, follow these steps to install it on Ubuntu:

Create a directory for extra CA certificates in /usr/share/ca-certificates:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/share/ca-certificates/extra
```

Copy the CA .crt file to this directory:

```
sudo cp foo.crt /usr/share/ca-certificates/extra/foo.crt
```

Let Ubuntu add the .crt file's path relative to /usr/share/ca-certificates to /etc/ca-certificates.conf:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates
```

This is an old post, but this is they only thing that I found that worked.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the exact same error and for some reason restarting my pc solved the error. Maybe it works for somone else too :P

Answer (score 0):

If it's a public repo, just clone using `https`. No need to use passwords or setup SSH keys.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to push/pull any repository from local to remote(git hub)
first checkout

```
$ git push https://<git-hub url>
```

working fine with username and passwd credential

```
$ git push git@<git-hub url>
```

> fail
>   Could not read remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

this means you need to add **id_rsa.pub** to **authorized_keys**

```
goto 
$ cd /home/admin/.ssh
$ls
$vi authorized_keys
add id_rsa keys(n no of keys you can add)
ssh-rsa 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 stace@pretend-machine
ssh-rsa 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 stace@another-machine

:wq!
```

goto `github-->settings--->ssh---->add new key---->id_rsa.pub`

```
$git push git@<git-hub url>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Pycharm on Ubuntu the solution is to use https instead of SSH 
for example : 
*https://github.com/Bedo1212/myrepo.git*

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SSH, make sure you're using a network that allows SSH. Most public networks allow only HTTP(S) traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Hi my problem was that my client did not ask if I recognized the key. Opening a terminal and doing `ssh -T git@github.com` worked. The response in the terminal asked if I wanted to add the key, I said yes and after that, my client worked fine

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, Until I realized, I was running my machine through a proxy address for my internet connection and it happens to close the host connection. This could be one of the few reasons too.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had followed all the steps mentioned in [Adding new ssh key](https://help.github.com/en/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account) and rest of the auxiliary links related to this issue.
But the issue was network access. Solution - using VPN to access my Github Enterprise. (in my case Georgia Tech VPN for github.gatech.edu)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I generated new key pairs but forgot to update public key in github.com (settings).

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to this is delete the old ssh key from github/gitlab and add the same key again. This is easy work around and you have to hussle with anything