# Github Repo - 'fatal: Could not read from remote repository.'

Tags: git, github

I'm unable to clone from a work github account repo.  I have gone through the steps of generating an ssh key pair and uploading the public key to my work github account.  I see with a verbose log clone `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvv" git clone git@github.com:<workAccount>/repo.git` that the authentication succeeds with the public key.  Therefore, I believe this is not an ssh auth problem.

But, when I run `ssh -T git@github.com`, it reads:

`Hi AlexanderBollbach! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.`

Now `AlexanderBollbach` is the name of my personal github account, not my work github account.  So it makes sense that I might get this error `'Could not read from remote repository.'` as my personal github account wouldn't have read privileges from my work github account.

My question is therefore, how can I associate this ssh cloning process with the right github account?  In the reading I've gone on ssh, I've not understood any concept of how ssh could be associated with one github account versus another.  I would greatly appreciate not just a fix but a proper understanding of how succeeding with the private/public key in this case just wasn't sufficient in cloning the repo.

Comment: Where did you save the key for your work account? Try using that with `ssh-agent` and `ssh-add`, as in `ssh-agent bash` followed by `ssh-add ~/.ssh/work_ed25519` and the clone. Or just `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i $HOME/.ssh/work_ed25519"`.

Comment: that didn't do it.  I'm still confused about how `ssh -T git@github.com` prints out my personal github user account name.  How is ssh associated with one github account vs another.  i don't get that.

Comment: It’s all about the private key you use, which will default to `~/.ssh/id_*`. Do you have anything in your `.ssh/config`, or is `ssh` an alias? And are you sure the SSH key you used when trying last time was actually associated with your work GitHub account?

Comment: all i did was key-gen a new key pair, submit the public key to github ( the work account) and try to clone.  so the fact that ssh is some how associated with my personal account is totally mysterious to me.  in the config file i did as you said, and told ssh to use that newly generated key.  i don't think ssh is an alias.  this is all just way over my head.

Answer (score 2):

"I'm still confused about how `ssh -T git@github.com` prints out my personal github user account name":
Simple: if the default public key `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` is registered in your public account, that account would be the one displayed in a `ssh -Tv git@github.com`.

If you want to manage multiple account (especially when it comes to pushing, which requires clear authentication and ownership of the target repo), you need an `~/.ssh/config` file, as [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12066973/6309).

```
#Personal GitHub
Host persgh
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_perso

#Personal Work
Host workgh
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_work
```

Then, to successfully clone your private repo:

```
git clone workgh:<workAccount>/<workRepo>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Solution from [Tombart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20714212/5157221):

Make sure you have correct url in `~/.git/config`:

```
url = git@github.com:<workAccount>/repo.git
```

If it's your first push, you'll need to set up correct upstream

```
$ git push -u origin master
```

You can check which key is used by:

```
$ ssh -vvv git@github.com
```

This should work.

#### Helpful resources

- [Could not read from remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16245606/5157221)
- [git: fatal: Could not read from remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13509293/5157221)